# Finding eigenvalues of a matrix with two unknowns

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been asked to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
216k^3&-108k^2&18k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm just not sure how to work it out as it gives me two unknowns, both the lambda and the k. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realise the matrix would come oout that way, it's a 3*3

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.

Comment: On the first row 0,1,1, on the second, 0,0,1 and on the third, 216k^3, -108k^2, 18K so it works out as a 3*3 matrix

Comment: @user217384: read the tutorial. In the meantime, I have put your matrix in $\LaTeX$

Comment: It seems that your $\lambda$ will be dependent on $k$. That is why you have two unknowns.

Comment: Presumably, you would solve for $\lambda$ in terms of $k$. The logic is that once you are given $k$, you immediately know $\lambda$.

Comment: @AlexSilva I believe it is cubic

Comment: @graydad, You are right!

Answer (score 0):

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
a&b&c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$Ax=\lambda x$$

$$x_2+x_3=\lambda x_1$$

$$x_3=\lambda x_2$$

$$ a x_1+ b x_2 +c x_3=\lambda x_3$$

(1), (2)

$$x_2=\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} x_1$$

+(3)

$$ a x_1+ b \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} x_1 +(c -\lambda) \lambda \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}x_1=0$$

$$ a+ b \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} +(c -\lambda) \lambda \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}=0$$

The rest is solving $\lambda$